# ionic slide fixed at the center

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic4

hi i try this code to build slider

```
    <ion-slide>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-card mode="ios">
                    <ion-card-header>
                        <ion-img src="https://abrito.ir/uloader/UFD/4%20(1).jpg"></ion-img>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content>
                        Keep
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-slide>
```

but the problem is the slider content stick at the center of the page
and the huge empty space is front of the ion cards

fullcode:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mZzJHcXc54/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90CKP.png)

Comment: Just to inform you that I tried in Ionic 5 and it works as expected. Maybe you can try to remove `ion-row` and `ion-col` and add css-flexed div with ion-cards inside ...

Comment: @ZeroWorks i want to put them in a row

Comment: Change your device to Any Mobile view and see the spacing. it is working as expected.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib i want to remove space!

Comment: Don't use ion card then. Make your own div on flex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will achieve the same effect removing `ion-row` and `ion-col` and introducing a `div` with flex display. All in all, I think you should put `ion-grid` as the docs says.

Then,

**Solution 1**: Adding `ion-grid`

```html
<ion-slide>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-card mode="ios">
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-img src="https://abrito.ir/uloader/UFD/4%20(1).jpg"></ion-img>
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>
            Keep
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-slide>
```

**Solution 2**: Changing to `DIV`

```html
<ion-slide>
  <div class="rowofcards">
    <ion-card mode="ios">
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-img src="https://abrito.ir/uloader/UFD/4%20(1).jpg"></ion-img>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        Keep
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

and in page.scss:

```css
.rowofcards {
  display: flex;
}

.rowofcards > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Note you should have to apply more styles to achieve what you need.

Also, why do you put an image in ion-card-header?